# Selenium How to add ability to control what TestCases to run In VSTS - Visual Test Studio in release definition

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to ability to externally control what test cases to run on nightly build in VSTS-azure for selenium UI tests.
I want to be able to skip specific Tests from multiple TestFixtures on the release task.

Currently I am using the Test filter criteria option from the Visual Studio Test Task from the pipeline where I can pass individual Test Name to be executed like "Name = Test1, Test3, Test8". Also I can use the Category Tag instead of Name. But way Limits me use

```
Name = Test1, Test3, Test8 || Category =  Category2 || Priority = P4
```

I wand to control which to execute and which to exclude from my nightly run t from my testsuite which contains around 200 tests.

Is this Possible can we add some file where I can have a switch to control the run???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some file that we can config which tests to include or exclude.

But it might be achieved with powershell.You can have a try with below.

If you are familiar with powershell and [dotnet vstest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest?tabs=netcore21) commandline. You can write powershell script to run the tests(You may need to checkin this script file to your repo). You can define different script files with different test filters. So each time when you run your pipeline you can just select the corresponding script file to run.

And aslo in the pipeline add a powershell task to run the tests instead of Visual Studio Test Task.

Below powershell script and powershell task are only for reference:

```
param(
[string]$source,
[string]$repos = "SelenNunit",
[string]$config
)

$path = $source +"\" +$repos+ "\"+ $repos+ "\"+ "\bin\" +$config

dotnet vstest $path\SelenNunit.exe /TestCaseFilter:"name=test1" /logger:"trx"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, powershell might help.
But I was thinking instead of executing tests directly from powershell we might just get the list of tests to be executed from the script and pass that as an argument to the Test Filter Criteria. I have a script which return me the list like " /Tests: RegressionTest.UploadFileOfWrongFormat , AdministrationTests.ADM0101". when I try to pass this as argument to VIsual Studio Test it does not work for multiple tests works fine when we have only one test.